# how to scale up update operations to a sql server table?

Tags: sql-server, scalability, deadlock, updates

How to design your database for this requirement?

Data is in a single table. Its quite hige too. My app starts many threads all of which connect to the database and update the same table; each thread would try updating a different row...

However the obdervation was that the update operation did not complete since it entered into a deadlock scenario. Later came to learn this was probably due to sql server's lock escalation mechanism.

So my requirement in short is that my database should handle massive number of update operations to a single table. What are the strategies to handle it?

Massive update operations, I imagine, would also cause a bottleneck due to I/o. Because a classical hardisk has a single head which seeks data stored on a magnetic disk which rotates at high revs per second. Not aware of the technological advancement in this area, but wouldn't a db designer be concerned about these issues too? How to handle these kind of problems?

Comment: "updating a different row" by that you mean each thread will update exactly one row?

Comment: @VasanthSundaralingam yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be nice if you provided numbers to huge and massive. As long as the ratio of total rows and updates is large, and the updates are scattered pretty evenly for all your indices, there should be very little contention.

The reason why indexing helps is that you can find the exact row that you need to update without locking all the others. So each of your thousands of simultaneous updates would each acquire exactly one exclusive lock, a few exclusive intents, and a bunch of shared locks. The other reason indexing helps is that the time spent on each query is tiny, reducing the number of active transactions and the chance of deadlocking.

Since your updates only update a single row, it's actually difficult to have them deadlock if you have the perfect index: update everything except the clustered key and only having the clustered index on the table. If you have multiple indices, the updates can grab parts of different indices and lock each other out.

If you are really having disk issues, then you need to get more RAM. Unless your load is truly random without any temporal locality, most of your updates will be served from RAM, and the only disk access you need is to write the transaction log, which is an append only log that doesn't require the disk to seek randomly.

So if you are speaking of a general strategy for optimally doing this, I would have a surrogate cluster key, make sure that updates only seek on this key, do not update this key, have no other wueires, and have only this index on the table. Then every update has exactly one exclusive row lock and no page/extent locks. There will never be a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

Someone told me indexing helps...but I find it hard to believe...

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2517/using-a-clustered-index-to-solve-a-sql-server-deadlock-issue/

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to tackle this issue

1) If your updates need not be be reflected immediately on the table, then you can ditch sql server and use the big data technology like Hadoop or green plum which will take care of this effectively for you.

2) If one does not satisfy, then try to update with (ROWLOCK), in general the page lock or table lock will be taken by sql server, when doing an update, the above hint might reduce the dead locks.

3) Ensure that your Update can be done quickly (performance tune).

4) Partition your table based on the good criteria, so that the your single table behaves as multiple tables, and reduces the contention.